# Remove unwanted str in Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, regex, pandas

'I am reading a csv file using panda read_csv which contains data,

```
Id;LibId;1;mod;modId;28;Index=10, Step=0, data=d720983f0000c0bf0000000014ae47bf0fe7c23ad1de3039;
Id;LibId;1;mod;modId;4;f9e9003e;
.
.
.
.
```

In the last column, I want to remove the Index, Step, data= and want to retain the hex value part.

I have created a list with the unwanted values and used regex but nothing seem to work.

```
to_remove = ['Index','Step','data=']
rex = '[' + re.escape (''. join (to_remove )) + ']'
output_csv['Column_name'].str.replace(rex , '', regex=True)
```

Comment: Try `to_remove = ['Index','Step','data=']` and then `output_csv['Column_name'] = output_csv['Column_name'].str.replace('|'.join([re.escape(x) for x in to_remove]), '', regex=True)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that you fix your code using

```py
to_remove = ['Index','Step','data=']
output_csv['Column_name'] = output_csv['Column_name'].str.replace('|'.join([re.escape(x) for x in to_remove]), '', regex=True)
```

The `'|'.join([re.escape(x) for x in to_remove])` part will create a regex like `Index|Step|data\=` and will match any of the `to_remove` substrings.

Answer (score 0):

Input (added columns name for reference, can be avoided):

```
col1;col2;col3;col4;col5;col6;col7
Id;LibId;1;mod;modId;28;Index=10, Step=0, data=d720983f0000c0bf0000000014ae47bf0fe7c23ad1de3039
Id;LibId;1;mod;modId;28;Index=10, Step=0, data=d7203ad1de3039
Id;LibId;1;mod;modId;28;Index=10, Step=0, data=d720e47bf0fe7c23ad1de3039
```

Code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(r"check.csv", sep=";")
df["col7"].replace(regex=True, to_replace="(Index=)(.*)(data=)", value="", inplace=True)
```

This will extract only the hex value from "data" part and remove everything else. Do not forget about `inplace=True`.